# Jackson Json with nested parametric classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

Listing:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Listing<T> {
    List<Thing<T>> children;

    public List<Thing<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Thing<T>> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Thing:

```
public class Thing<T> {

    private String type;
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Link:

```
public class Link {
    private String author;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

and here's an example of serialization and deserialization...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Link link1 = new Link();
    link1.setAuthor("JohnDoe");

    Link link2 = new Link();
    link2.setAuthor("MaryJane");

    List<Thing<Link>> things = new ArrayList<Thing<Link>>();

    Thing<Link> thing1 = new Thing();
    thing1.setData(link1);
    thing1.setType("t3");

    Thing<Link> thing2 = new Thing();
    thing2.setData(link2);
    thing2.setType("t3");

    things.add(thing1);
    things.add(thing2);

    Listing<Link> listing = new Listing<Link>();
    listing.setChildren(things);


    Thing<Listing> thing = new Thing<Listing>();
    thing.setType("listing");
    thing.setData(listing);

    File jsonFile = new File("src/testMap.txt");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(jsonFile, thing);

    //String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"listing\",\"data\":{\"children\":[{\"type\":\"t3\",\"data\":{\"author\":\"JohnDoe\"}},{\"type\":\"t3\",\"data\":{\"author\":\"MaryJane\"}}]}}";
    JavaType jsonType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Thing.class, Listing.class);
    Thing<Listing> readThing = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, jsonType);


}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the Things contained in the Listing in the sample code above are not parametrized with Link, so their data field is returned as an Object (which is actually LinkedHashMap).

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
List<Thing<Link>> readListingChildren = readThing.getData().getChildren();
String author = readListingChildren.get(0).getData().getAuthor();
```

My question is, how would I get this to work using Jackson json?

Note: there will be multiple different types of objects contained by Things, and a Thing's data member's type is defined (or should be defined) by the data object's "type" field, using strings such as t1, t2, t3, etc. which map to different classes.

Comment: I guess I can use something like:
JavaType listingType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Listing.class, Link.class);
    JavaType jsonType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Thing.class, listingType);'

Comment: Correct: if you don't do that, type to use is `Thing<Listing<?>>`, which is about same as `Thing<Listing<Object>>`. And with `Object`, JSON Object becomes a `Map`. So you do need to give full type definition; implied type variables do not get substituted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve a serialized String like

```
{
    "data":{
        "type":"listing",
        "children":[
            {
                    "data":{
                    "type":"t3",
                    "author":"JohnDoe"
                }
            },
            {
                "data":{
                    "type":"t3",
                    "author":"MaryJane"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and to use the `type` information to correctly deserialize the concrete class you may use

```
@JsonTypeName("listing")
public class Listing<T> {
    List<Thing<T>> children;

    public List<Thing<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(final List<Thing<T>> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Thing<T> {
    private T data;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(Link.class),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(Listing.class)
    })
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

---

```
@JsonTypeName("t3")
public class Link {
    private String author;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(final String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for - is there a tutorial somewhere on how to use Jackson's various attributes?

Comment: There is a short tutorial about [Polymorphic Type Handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) or an overview of the [Jackson Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations).